# Upgraded to Dell E6430s from E6420 and lost ability to run three external monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I was able to run 3 external monitors, plus my main laptop display—for a total of 4—on my older Dell Latitude E6420. With this newer Dell Latitude E6430s laptop, I able to detect all three monitors, however, they are greyed out and can’t be identified. Does anyone know if this is a limitation of the new hardware, that it can’t run out to two or three external displays?

Screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAIm1.jpg

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official tech specs, the [Dell Latitude E6420](http://www.dell.com/il/en/business/p/latitude-e6420/pd) uses the Intel® HD Graphics 3000 and the [Dell Latitude E6430s](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-e6430s/pd) uses Intel® HD Graphics 3000 for Intel Core i3 Processors and the Intel® HD Graphics 4000 for Intel Core i3/i5/i7 3xxxM Processors.

So I assume that if the behavior is not the same as the Dell Latitude E6420, you are using a Dell Latitude E6430s with the Intel® HD Graphics 4000.

Looking at [this support thread on Intel’s site](https://communities.intel.com/thread/43939) it seems like you are not alone in the confusion and there is an answer from “rtm_tech” which states:

> This information is straight from the **Configuration 3-Displays FAQ**
>   page. For the Intel HD 4000 to actually support the three independent
>   display configuration, the following criteria need to be met:
>
> - If two of the displays are DisplayPort* monitors
> - If one of the displays is an Intel® Wireless Display (Intel® WiDi)
> - If the built-in display is an Embedded DisplayPort1 (eDP) not a LVDS

That answer refers to the [“Configuration 3-Displays FAQ”](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm) which describes itself as:

> This document lists many of the possible ways to connect a computer to
>   three displays and the ways to optimize your viewing experience.

So I would recommend looking through that to see what you might have to adjust to get your Dell Latitude E6430s laptop setup just the way you would like it to.

Additionally [this thread on the Dell support site](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19464513) refers to driver issues and the answer from “NIH tech” states:

> I just discovered the answer today: I had previously checked video
>   card updates, and found two, and installed them. But in re-checking I
>   found that they were for 32 bit Windows OS - the laptop I was having
>   problems with has the 64 bit OS. Once I downloaded and installed that
>   driver fix - problem solved!

But again, that is just a clue as to what might be happening. Perhaps it’s a simply configuration misunderstanding on your part? Perhaps it’s a driver issue? Hopefully this info will set you on the right track.